# Permutations of the word "arrangement" with restrictions (counting)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many permutations are there in the word "arrangement" that have **exactly two** of the following consecutive letters in them: aa,ee,rr,nn? For example: "aarrngement"

Comment: Hint: Use Inclusion/Exclusion. The two kinds that are together can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. For each way, count the words. But this overcounts the words that have three kinds together. Continue.

Comment: The toffee problem is really quite different, that idea is a minor component here.

Comment: This is a much more complex problem compared to the toffee problem.

Comment: This problem is not a duplicate of the toffee problem since the toffee problem does not require an inclusion-exclusion argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inclusion-exclusion can be applied, but it is a bit tricky. not exactly run-of-the-mill.

ways with at least $2$ together - ways with at least $3$ together + ways with all $4$ together

= $\binom42\binom22\frac{9!}{2!2!} - \binom43\binom32\frac{8!}{2!} + \binom44\binom427! = 332,640$

Try to work out the logic for the extra coefficients..

---

*Added, a way without inclusion-exclusion:*

Let us take $AA, EE$ together as $\mathcal A, \mathcal E$, respectively.

Let us then separate the $RR$ by inserting in gaps $\uparrow \mathcal{ \large A}\uparrow \mathcal{\large E}\uparrow N\uparrow N\uparrow G\uparrow M\uparrow T\uparrow$ and permute the rest. 
This can be done in $\binom82\times\frac{7!}{2!}$ ways.

Now, from such arrangements, subtract those with $NN$ together,
$\uparrow \mathcal{ \large A}\uparrow \mathcal{\large E}\uparrow\mathcal{\large N}\uparrow G\uparrow M\uparrow T\uparrow$ in $\binom72\times 6!$ ways

$\binom82 \times \frac{7!}{2!} - \binom72 \times 6! = 55440$

And since there are $\binom42 = 6$ ways of choosing the initial "together pair", final answer is $6\times 55440 = 332,640$, as before.

Comment: You provided two nice solutions to a tricky problem.   However, there is a typographical error you should fix.  The $21$ in your calculation of the $55440$ arrangements in which AA and EE are the only double letters should be $2!$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Thanks, corrected.